# Верно ли расставлены запятые в этом предложении? Нужно ли обособлять часть "и густыми бровями того же богатого оттенка" с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, ссп

Особенно потому, что со своими необычайно темными, почти черными волосами, блестящими, как дорогой мех, и густыми бровями того же богатого оттенка был не похож на местных парней.

Comment: Это довольно бестактно давать лучший ответ просто на основании рейтингов участников. Одно дело, когда ответ содержит какие-то железные доказательства в вид, например, ссылки или более поддерживается участниками,   но в данных случаях, учитывая еще крайне сомнительное качество признанных лучшими ответов, это неуважение к людям, которые тратили время давая ответы на ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки расставлены верно, дополнительное обособление **не требуется:**

*Особенно потому, что со своими необычайно темными, почти черными волосами, блестящими, как дорогой мех, и густыми бровями того же богатого оттенка был не похож на местных парней.*

Здесь существительное "брови" имеет два **равноправных** определения (согласованное и несогласованное).

Однако для прочтения и понимания смысла предложение не очень удобно, поэтому можно предложить такую редакцию:

*Особенно же потому, что  он не был похож на других парней – **как необычайно темными, почти черными волосами, блестящими, как дорогой мех, так и густыми бровями того же оттенка.***

Тире здесь факультативано.

Comment: ‟Почти черными” является уточнением по отношению к ‟необычайно темными”. Не указать на это — грубая ошибка в вашем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

‟Почти чёрными” обособляется запятыми, так как это уточнение. [Вот ссылка. ( Пункт 4. Уточняющие определения со значением цвета, размера, возраста и т. д)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118)

После ‟и густыми бровями того же богатого оттенка” запятая не ставится, так как после однородных членов запятая не ставится, если на это нет несвязанных с однородными членами причин, вроде последующего союза ‟но” или придаточной части.